# Conditionally format row only when value appears for the first time

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

I currently have a conditional formatting rule that applies when a value is at the top of a group of rows with the same value.  As long as the rows aren't broken up with space or different value, the rule applies correctly.

```js
=IF($A2<>"",if($A1<>$A2:$A, TRUE, FALSE),"")
```

What I would like is for this same rule to apply even if there is a different value or blank between the top and current row.

In other words, currently, as long as I have rows like:

```
A
A
A
```

The top row will be formatted creating sort of a "header row."  But if anything breaks it up, such as:

```
A
A
B
A
```

The "A" after "B" will then become ANOTHER header row.  I would like for ONLY the first appearance to be formatted and all subsequent appearances remain unformatted.  I hope that makes sense.

[Here's my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit?usp=sharing) I use this formatting on 'Items' and 'taskData'

Edit:
I'm only wanting the first occurrence in the entire column to be formatted.  And every first occurrence.

```
A <--- formatted
A <--- not formatted
B <--- formatted

A <--- not formatted
B <--- not formatted
C <--- formatted
B <--- not formatted
D <--- formatted
D <--- not formatted
A <--- not formatted
```

My objective is if there is already a header row started, I don't want to inadvertently start the same group further down the column (there will eventually be 100's of rows). Hopefully, that makes better sense.

Comment: [Here's my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit?usp=sharing) on tab 'taskData'

Comment: @player0 Thank you for your reply! As usual, I don't think I explained my goal clearly enough. I added an edit to the OP. Hopefully that will better explain my goal. Thank you again, as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF($A2<>"",IF($A1<>"",IF($A2<>"",""),1),"")
```

[image: 0]

---

or like this:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1
```

[image: 0]